# How to iterate over hash with class QT

Tags: c++, qt, hash

I have declaration

```
QHash<int,SomeClass*>* index_hash;
```

definition in .h file

I have this definition in cpp.file

```
QHash<int, SomeClass*> ::iterator i;


for (i =  index_hash.begin(); i !=  index_hash.end(); ++i)
                 
               { 
                    
                    
                }
```

I got C3867 error

and

error C2446: ==: no 'const int &(__thiscall QHash<Key,T>::iterator::* )(void) const' в 'int'

How can I iterate over hash?

I try

```
QHashIterator<int, SomeClass *> i(index_hash);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    i.next();
    //qDebug() << i.key() << ": " << i.value();
}
```

But I get QHashIterator<Key,T>::QHashIterator(const QHash<Key,T> &): can not 1 из 'QHash<Key,T> *' в 'const QHash<Key,T> &'

So I try

```
        QHashIterator<int, SomeClass *> it(*index_hash);

        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            it.next();
            int x = it.key();
            //it.value()=item; // how can I do it?

            
            //qDebug() << i.key() << ": " << i.value();
        }
```

That work. But I need to change value

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with operator precedence. You can do:

```
for (i =  (*index_hash).begin(); i !=  (*index_hash).end(); ++i)
```

Or shorter:

```
for (i =  index_hash->begin(); i !=  index_hash->end(); ++i)
```

Comment: Compiler said  use "&QHash<Key,T>::iterator::key when I try for (i =  index_hash->begin(); i !=  index_hash->end(); ++i) C3867:

Comment: I have found some answer by myself but I need to change hash value

Comment: You can answer your own question here and show what you found.

Comment: OK. The answer to topic. But in new theme there would be new question.

Answer (score 0):

`QHashIterator<int, SomeClass *> i(index_hash);`

=>
`QHashIterator<int, SomeClass *> it(*index_hash);`

or

```
 QHash<int, CLift*> ::iterator it; 
 for (it =  index_hash->begin(); it !=  index_hash->end(); ++it)
   
               { 
                    
                    
               }
```